# construct ip::address from ipv4_address

Tags: c++, boost-asio, ip-address, endpoint

I am using the following code to initialize an endpoint.

```
       endPt = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.1.21"), 
                                                            boost::lexical_cast<int>(portNo));
```

What is the right way to initialize an endpoint if the ipaddress is in form of a char array ( say argv[1]) or a string object read from a config file. Boost docs in [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address.html) give the following.

```
    "Construct an address from an IPv4 address."
```

Is the above the right way? Please help me with a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet, the string `"192.168.1.21"` is in fact a char array such as would be obtained from `argv[1]`.

```
endPt = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
    boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(argv[1]),
    boost::lexical_cast<int>(portNo)
);
```